# Remove rows from dataframes not present in dataframes in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a hundreds pandas dataframes such as these:

```
Df1 = 
    MD    A    B    C  
    r1    6    3    9   
    r2    2    1    1  
    r3    5    7    2  
    r4    8    2    0

Df2 = 
    MD    A    B    C  
    r1    1    7    1  
    r2    6    3    0  
    r3    3    1    8
    r4    1    7    4
```

I also have one dictionary like this (except with a number of keys and values to reflect the number of dataframes):

```
Dict = {'D1', MD
              r1
              r4
        [2 rows x 1 columns]
        'D2', MD
              r1
              r2
              r3
        [3 rows x 1 columns]}
```

What I need is a way to go through the dictionary, and for each dataframe and corresponding key (I.e. Df1 and D1, and Df2 and D2), remove the rows not present in the "dictionary-value dataframe".

So for Df1, I need to go to the key D1 and remove the rows that are not in the dataframe for this key. That is, remove r2 and r3 from Df1.

So the result I want would be:

```
Df1 = 
    MD    A    B    C  
    r1    6    3    9   
    r4    8    2    0

Df2 = 
    MD    A    B    C  
    r1    1    7    1  
    r2    6    3    0  
    r3    3    1    8
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

PS. If it is easier to keep the rows instead of removing them, that would also be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I just print the values, but you could reassign the DataFrame.

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"r1": [1,2,3], "r2": [4,5,6], "r3": [7,8,9]}, columns=["A", "B", "C"], orient="index")
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"r1": [1,2,3], "r2": [4,5,6], "r3": [7,8,9]}, columns=["A", "B", "C"], orient="index")

>>> dfs = [df1, df2]
>>> dfs

[    A  B  C
 r1  1  2  3
 r2  4  5  6
 r3  7  8  9,
     A  B  C
 r1  1  2  3
 r2  4  5  6
 r3  7  8  9]

lookup = {"d1": ["r1", 'r2'], 'd2': ["r2", "r3"]}

for rows, df in zip(lookup.values(), dfs):
    print(df.loc[rows])

    A  B  C
r1  1  2  3
r2  4  5  6
    A  B  C
r2  4  5  6
r3  7  8  9
```

EDIT

If you're DataFrames aren't in a dict and are just available as global variables, **providing the keys match** in your lookup to the variable name, you could do something like this:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"r1": [1,2,3], "r2": [4,5,6], "r3": [7,8,9]}, columns=["A", "B", "C"], orient="index")
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"r1": [1,2,3], "r2": [4,5,6], "r3": [7,8,9]}, columns=["A", "B", "C"], orient="index")

>>> lookup = {"df1": ["r1", 'r2'], 'df2': ["r2", "r3"]}

# Use the reference key from lookup, to grab the relevant DataFrame
# then index rows using .loc with the corresponding values from lookup
for key in lookup.keys():
    print(globals()[key].loc[lookup[key]])
```

Otherwise, I'd recommend just putting them in a datastructure you can iterate over easily, as demonstrated in the original answer.

Comment: The dataframes I have are not in a dictionary. They are standalone. Is there any way to do this on multiple individual dataframes or should I make a dictionary out of all the dataframes first?

Comment: @FrustratedApe I've updated my answer with an example of what I think you mean. I think it'll be easier if you get the DataFrames in a data structure you can iterate over, as you won't have to worry about keys matching, providing everything is in the same order. I have however included an example of dealing with DataFrames that are just in the global context.

Comment: I tried doing it the way you suggest in your edit, but I end up getting the following error:
`ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key`


. If I just try to print key or globals()[key] I get the expected results. I.e.:

`for key in lookup.keys():
    print(globals()[key]) `

or

`for key in lookup.keys():
    print(globals()[key]) `

Comment: This works, but I had to convert the dataframes to lists firsts.